# How do I get two rows next to each other with columns?

Tags: html, css

I've an issue with rows and columns.
Whatever I try, I can't fix it.

I get....see [capture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQXOw.png),
but I want something like....see [capture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YWd5.png).
I'll also insert my code so that you can see it.

HTML

```
 <div class="form">
  <b-row>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
  <b-row>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">
        </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.form {
    margin-top: 1%; 
    margin-bottom: 1%; border: 1px solid rgb(210, 210, 223);
}
```

Comment: why are you using two rows

Comment: Because I need to separate the columns.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
b-col {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <b-row>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">1
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">2
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">3
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">4
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">5
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">6
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">7
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
  <b-row>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">8
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">9
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">10
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">11
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">12
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">13
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="1">
      <b-form-input size="sm" type="text" v-model="connection.bla" placeholder="bla">14
      </b-form-input>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</div>
```

Comment: tnx mate. your code works perfect on jsfiddle and on an online editor. but not in visual studio code...I dont understand why, I will debug my code..tnx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the items to be in order? otherwise you can just do this

```
b-row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: yes, I want them to be in order. btw I also tried the same as your code, it's not working unfortunately.